# Regex-How to prevent repeated special characters?

Tags: java, c#, regex, pcre, regular-language

I don't have an experience on Regular Expressions. I need to a regular expression which doesn't allow to repeat of special characters (+-*/& etc.)
The string can contain digits, alphanumerics, and special characters.

This should be valid : abc,df

This should be invalid : abc-,df

i will be really appreciated if you can help me ! Thanks for advance.

Comment: What else do you consider a special character? `-` and `,` to me are equally 'special'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions presented so far match a string that is **not** allowed.

But the tilte is *How to prevent...*, so I assume that the regex
should match the **allowed** string. It means that the regex should:

- match the **whole** string if it does not contain 2
  consecutive special characters,
- not match otherwise.

You can achieve this putting together the following parts:

- `^` - start of string anchor,
- `(?!.*[...]{2})` - a *negative lookahead* for 2 consecutive special
  characters (marked here as `...`), in any place,
- a regex matching the whole (non-empty) string,
- `$` - end of string anchor.

So the whole regex should be:

```
^(?!.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_+={}[\]|\\;:'",<.>\/?]{2}).+$
```

Note that within a char class (between `[` and `]`) a backslash
escaping the following char should be placed before `-` (if in
the middle of the sequence), closing square bracket,
a backslash itself and `/` (regex terminator).

Or if you want to apply the regex to **individual words** (not the whole
string), then the regex should be:

```
\b(?!\S*[!@#$%^&*()\-_+={}[\]|\\;:'",<.>\/?]{2})\S+
```

Comment: It works great, you saved my day. Really appreciated, thank you !

Answer (score 3):

`[\,\+\-\*\/\&]{2,}` Add more characters in the square bracket if you want.
Demo https://regex101.com/r/CBrldL/2

Comment: Nice and simple one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regex to match the invalid string.

```
[^A-Za-z0-9]{2,}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[^\w!\s]{2,}` This would be a shortest version to match any two consecutive special characters (ignoring space)

If you want to consider space, please use `[^\w]{2,}`